# Dbeaver table editing is locked

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

[image: dbeaver lock image]

Couldn't delete/modify rows in tables.
How to edit my tables?
DB: pgsql

Tried refreshing and connecting again to the db. But the table still was locked
What are the possible methods to try upon?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Does your table have primary key? Does your user have write privileges? Is your connection read-only?

Comment: *How to edit my tables?*, what about good old `update`, `delete` and `insert`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you try to disconnect from the database and then connecting again?
Seems like the lock will disappear when running a new query against table.